# AD domain using powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am logged onto a domain "A" server.

Although using this command, I have fetched AD group data for "B" domain.

```
Get-ADGroup -Server B | select distinguishedname"
```

Can I still run the below command while logged on to "A" domain, to fetch Group members name for an AD group that exists in B domain?

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "SAMAccountName_B_Domain" | select name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to specify the Server again:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Server B -Identity "SAMAccountName_B_Domain" | select name
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. But had i been in a B domain server, would it still be required ?

Comment: With no Server specified, the command will search the domain the computer it's run on is part of.